# ASP.NET Core Pages Stuck on Loading in Debug Mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core web application. Everything is working perfectly, but suddenly when I start the application with debugging, all of pages are stuck on loading.

[image]

In this screenshot, it just sends a get request and return the page. Nothing heavy but the request never finishes. I've also added a debug point and get function returns view.

Index function

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">ASD</button>
</div>
```

When I run the application without debugging, everything is working perfectly. What is the problem here?

Comment: If the request isn’t finishing, then the process is likely being stopped by your debugger. Check that the execution isn’t paused by a breakpoint or something else and make sure to hit “continue” if it’s clickable.

Comment: I've deleted all breakpoints already but it's same.

Comment: What do you get if you do a line by line debug? Maybe isnt reach the endpoint at all

Comment: I've debugged function. It completes and returns View successfully. It's like a bug or something. When it happens, I'cant even stop loading page or refresh. It just stuck on loading

Comment: Hi @ErtugrulSungur, although you remove the breakpoint, it is still stuck on pending?

Comment: I have the same issue as well. It still works when I'm debugging with Edge instead of Chrome though.

Comment: It's normal now but I haven't changed anything